# Logo and two text div centering verically and horizontally on the page

Tags: html, css, layout

What is the best way and best practice to achieve this layout? Meaning it will stay consistent on iPad, Android or desktop. CSS Grids? Flexbox? Logo div should be centered on the page vertically and horizontally. Text divs should be centered in the middle of the logo div.

[here is the layout mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtLyg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right way, you could use anything you like, however i would suggest [flexbox](https://codepen.io/FabienGreard/pen/PQXemZ?q=flexbox%20position&limit=all&type=type-pens) for that demande, but you could do it with grid or so..

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; /* to meet your need or space-between*/
  align-items: center; /* vertical */
}
```

```css
.container{ /* get all the space */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container, .container > .item{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; /* horizontal, nice to try: center or space-between*/
  align-items: center; /* vertical */
}
    
.item {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.large{
  height: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { /* using media query to detect screen size */
  .container{
    flex-direction: column; /* switch display into column */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Text Div Centered</div>
  <div class="item large">Logo Centered</div>
  <div class="item">Text Div Centered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would i center this vertically?

Comment: Align-items, whats your problem ?

Comment: Also can this be responsive, go into a single column when lower than 480px width?

Comment: align the divs vertically on the page so it has the space padding on the top as on the bottom.

Comment: well i have updated my answer, with what i think you"re asking

Comment: Thanks that looks great. Is it possible to bring two text divs closer together?

Comment: Use margin property inside your items when you need to adjust thing

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a table? and remove border / cellspacing??

```css
   td {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td><div class="div1">test</div></td>
<td><div class="div2">test</div></td>
<td><div class="div3">test</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="div1">test</div></td>
<td><div class="div2">test</div></td>
<td><div class="div3">test</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No cannot use tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** to achieve that. At first create a `.flex` container with `display:flex` property. Now apply `flex:1` to its children. All its children acquire an equal width.

But from the image shown, your `Logo Div`s height is larger, then apply the same here on the individual element. But, if you observe, nothing is centered. So, in order to center every box, you need to use the properties `align-items:center` and `justify-content:center` on the `.flex`.

Even now the text inside is not centered, but the boxes are centered vertically and horizontally. To achieve the same on the children, apply `display:flex` and the same centering method described above to its children too. Now the content of the children i.e, the text inside is centered as well.

```css
.flex, .flex > div{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.flex > div{
  flex:1;
  height:80px;
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
.flex .logoDiv{
  height:150px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex'>
  <div class='textDiv'>Text Div Centered</div>
  <div class='logoDiv'>Logo Centered</div>
  <div class='textDiv'>Text Div Centered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to center vertically?

Comment: adding the properties: `align-items:center;` and ` justify-content:center;` to `display:flex` centers the content both vertically and horizontally.